# Stripping out static text from log messages and save only variables

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I know that there is a way to get rid of static text from log messages and keep only the variables part of the message in memory. But I am not sure exactly how it is done.

To give a concrete example to what I mean:

Here is some code for the client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_logging.h"
int main() {
   MY_CUSTOM_LOGGING_TECHNIQUE("This is message %d", int, 1);
   MY_CUSTOM_LOGGING_TECHNIQUE("This is message %d", int, 2);
   return 0;
}
```

And what should be done:

1. During compilation/build:

Generate XML file during compilation/build to give ID for each message:

```
<xml>

<message params=1>
<id>123456</id>
<text>This is message %d</text>
<param>int</param>
</message>

<message params=1>
<id>456342</id>
<text>This is message %d</text>
<param>int</param>
</message>

</xml>
```

2. During run time:
   only the ID of the message is stored along with values for the parameters in an appropriate structure (shown here as an array 'messages_array'):
   messages_array:

[image: messages_array]

3. During post-processing:
   The values saved during run-time are iterated through and combined with XML file saved during build. This post-processing step will generate the log file:

This is message 1
This is message 2

The main problem I am trying to solve here is "Not having to write static text to a file in the run-time. Instead, only the ID of the message and the value of the argument sent in the message.

So, how can I do this?

Comment: Does it have to be done in C or C++?  There are several other languages better designed for parsing text and generating XML.

Comment: @jmq the XML file is not the issue here. The main issue is stripping out the static text and saving only the value of the arguments in run-time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this is not possible with C without some additional preprocessing / postprocessing.

One solution would be using `__COUNTER__` macro with combination of -E gcc parameter and postprocessing that will generate XML file. See this example:

```
#define MY_LOG(string, ...) logPlaceholder(__COUNTER__, string); logFunction(__VA_ARGS__)

void logPlaceholder(int a, const char* str) {}

void logFunction(int param)
{
    printf("%d\n", param);
}

int main()
{
    MY_LOG("hello%d", 1);
    MY_LOG("world%d", 2);
    return 0;
}
```

You can replace `logFunction` by some variadic function to accept more parameters.

`logPlaceholder` will be optimized out since it is empty function - no string will be present in output binary.

It will generate something like this to stdout when compiled with -E parameter:

```
int main()
{
    logPlaceholder(0, "hello%d"); logFunction(1);
    logPlaceholder(1, "world%d"); logFunction(2);
    return 0;
}
```

When you redirect gcc output to file that you can postprocess - look for `logPlaceholder` string and generate XML with message number, string and all arguments.

However `__COUNTER__` is compiler specific (non-standard) and is global for all macros.

Comment: it is totally fine if it is compiler-specific.